# getrandbits does not produce constant length numbers

Tags: python, random

I use python 2.6.6. I use getrandbits(128) to get 128 bits random numbers.

```
a = random.getrandbits(128)
```

However, the number of bits are not always 128. Sometimes less than that. What is the reason for this? Is there any libraries that are more stable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each of those 128 bits can be 0 or 1; if the left-most bits are 0 your number will be smaller than 2 ** 127 but *they were still generated*. This is expected and perfectly normal behaviour.

If you need the left-most bit to be 1, always, use `randrange()` instead:

```
a = random.randrange(1 << 127, 1 << 128)
```

This generates a number that is guaranteed to have the first bit set to 1. Alternatively, generate a 127 bit number and add `1 << 127` to it:

```
a = random.getrandbits(127) + (1 << 127)
```

You can see this behaviour when formatting the `getrandbits()` output as 0-padded binary using the `format()` number:

```
>>> format(random.getrandbits(8), '08b')
'00011110'
>>> format(random.getrandbits(8), '08b')
'01000010'
>>> format(random.getrandbits(8), '08b')
'00110010'
>>> format(random.getrandbits(8), '08b')
'10101010'
>>> format(random.getrandbits(8), '08b')
'10000110'
```

The numbers are perfectly random, but sometimes the left-most bits end up `0`. By generating 1 bit fewer instead, and adding in the left-most bit set to 1, you half the number of random values you can generate but guarantee you see 'all' your bits:

```
>>> format(random.getrandbits(7) + (1 << 8), '08b')
'100010110'
>>> format(random.getrandbits(7) + (1 << 8), '08b')
'101111101'
>>> format(random.getrandbits(7) + (1 << 8), '08b')
'101000111'
>>> format(random.getrandbits(7) + (1 << 8), '08b')
'101011111'
```

It depends entirely on what you were trying to do if this is at all desirable.

Comment: In fact, there's a 50 % chance that the leftmost bit *will* be zero :)